# <return: > attribute equivalent in Visual Basic.Net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, attributes

I have a C# web method that I need to translate to VB.NET. The method has following attribute:

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("MethodName", Namespace = "http://namespaceurl")]
public CustomClass Method()
....
```

The method returns custom class as result.

How can I translate this to VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, thanks to http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Public Function Method() As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("MethodName", [Namespace] := "http://namespaceurl")> CustomClass
...
```